# How to define Yield and For for custom computation operation in F#

Tags: f#, computation-expression

I'm working on some DSL for my application and here's how I defined computation type and builder:

```
// expression type
type Action<'a,'b> = Action of ('a -> Async<'b>)

let runAction (Action r) ctx = r ctx
let returnF a = Action (fun _ -> async {return a})
let bind m f = Action (fun r -> async {
    let! a = runAction m r in return! runAction (f a) r
    })

let bindA ac f = Action (fun r -> async {
    let! a = ac in return! runAction (f a) r
    })

type ActionBuilder<'x>() =
  member this.Return(c) = returnF c
  member this.Zero()    = returnF ()
  member this.Delay(f)  = bind (returnF ()) f

  // binds both monadic and for async computations
  member this.Bind(m, f) = bind m f
  member this.Bind(m, f) = bindA m f

  member this.Combine(r1, r2) = bind r1 (fun () -> r2)
  member this.For(s:seq<_>, f)  = Action (fun x -> async {
    for i in s do runAction (f i) x |> ignore
    })

  // here's the attempt to implement 'need' operations

  [<CustomOperation("need")>]
  member this.Need(Action a,  targets: string list) =
    Action (fun x ->
      let r = a x
      printfn "need(%A, [%A])" a targets
      r)

   member this.For(a, f)  = bindA a f
   member this.Yield(()) =
    returnF ()

let action = ActionBuilder<string>()

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// other functions for Action

/// Gets action context
let getCtx = Action (fun ctx -> async {return ctx})


let needFn res = action {
    let! ctx = getCtx
    printfn "need([%A]) in %A" res ctx
  }
```

The resulting code is supposed to be:

```
let program1 = fun filename -> action {
  let! a = async {return 123}
  let f = a+1

  // need ["def"; "dd"]
  do! needFn ["def"; "dd"]
  printfn "after need"

  for i in [0..10] do
    do! Async.Sleep (1)
    printfn "i: %A" i

  let! d = async {return f}
  let! ctx = getCtx
  printfn "ctx: %A, %A" ctx f
}

Async.RunSynchronously(runAction (program1 "m.c") "abc")
```

Now I would like to change `do! needFn ["def"; "dd"]` syntax to a nicer one by defining **"need" custom operation**, but getting various complains from compiler. Is it correct approach or I'm misusing the computation expressions?

**The other issue** is that `for` does not work if `do!` is used inside loop body.

Answer (score 1):

After reading papers, by trial and error method I came to the following `for` implementation (`Yield` builder method is not required):

```
    let forF (e: seq<_>) prog =
    usingF (e.GetEnumerator()) (fun e ->
        whileF
            (fun () -> e.MoveNext())
            ((fun () -> prog e.Current) |> delayF)
    )
```

Full source code for computation expression builder could be found in [the target project](https://github.com/FakeBuild/Xake/blob/dev/src/core/RecipeBuilder.fs). The whole project is a variation of Fake build system.

Note: Action was renamed to Recipe. `need` operator cannot be implemented at all.

Comment: Just a note for posterity: if you write a DSL, i.e. just a bunch of `CustomOperator` stuff in a class, all you need is `Yield(())`, which is your entry point. No need for `For` or any of the other default methods.

Comment: @Abel you must have meant declarative DSLs unlike bound calculations (with Bind). In that case both While and For are of course redundant.

Comment: Correct, that's what I meant with "if you write a DSL", I wasn't very precise in my language ;).